# How do I make my default GW route permanently on Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, route, static-routes, defaults

I have 2 EC2 instances that run Ubuntu (VM1: `172.0.1.11` and VM2: `172.2.1.12`).

I want to make a default Gateway to my Routers R1which its addresses are the following respectively `172.0.1.8`and `172.2.1.13`.

In VM1: I did `sudo ip route add default via 172.0.1.8`. On the other side, in VM2: `sudo ip route add default via 172.2.1.13`. Both routes are working.

However, when I reboot the instances, I lose that default route.

Is there any way to permanently save the default route?

I tried in both sides the following code modifying /ect/network/interfaces?

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.2.1.10 (172.0.1.11 VM1)
netmask 255.255.255.240
up route add -net 172.2.0.0 (172.0.0.0) netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 172.2.1.13 (172.0.1.8)
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu do you use? Recent releases have migrated to new network configuration system - netplan.

Answer (score 0):

You should add in file `/etc/network/interfaces` line like this:

```
gateway 172.0.1.8
```

(for VM1)
and

```
gateway 172.0.1.13
```

for VM2
And then restart the network or reboot the VMs

Comment: It did not work, either!

Comment: @TimLuka, did you add it for interface? Like this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/403429/680869

Answer (score 0):

Your /etc/network/interfaces file should looks like below after adding route.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
      address <IP>
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      up route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 gw 192.168.1.1
```

After that

```
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
```

Or restart your vm.

Comment: It didn't work. I tried the given modification above. i could not write it in a comment

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

#### on VM1

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
...
up route add default via 172.0.1.8 dev eth0
```

#### on VM2

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
...
up route add default via 172.2.1.13 dev eth0
```